# Installing apk on a rooted device

Tags: android, apk, root

I use about 100 devices for testing. Believe me, I can't use any other solution.
What I need from you guys is a way to install updated APK's on these devices.
The only way I found is to root the devices, which I did, and install the updated APK.
My problem is that I didn't find how to install an APK programmatically from an app that is not a system app.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibilities, you may buy **soti** service. Their app let you mange the divices that you have enroll (for instance, install/update an app). It does not require root privilege as long as I remember. Check it out [soti.net](https://www.soti.net)